# AsyncTask падает при парсинге html страницы

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, парсер

Суть приложения такова, что я ввожу какие-то символы, которыми дополняются определенный url и с этого url уже идет парсинг нужных мне значений. При вводе правильных значений все работает как нужно, но вот если ввожу случайно символы которых не существует то приложение падает (хотя экспешены вроде все прописаны). Вот текст ошибки:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: m.masyuk.com.fb.stackinfo, PID: 3901
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at m.masyuk.com.fb.stackinfo.MainActivity$SetInfo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:260)
at m.masyuk.com.fb.stackinfo.MainActivity$SetInfo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

И сам код:

```
    private class SetInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private TextView textViewForImport;
    private int numImport;
    private String code;

    SetInfo(TextView textViewForImport, String code, int numImport) {
        this.textViewForImport = textViewForImport;
        this.code = code;
        this.numImport = numImport;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        String stackInfo = "";

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Element mc_element = doc.select(code).get(numImport);
            stackInfo = mc_element.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stackInfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        textViewForImport.setText(aVoid);
    }
}
```

ЗЫ Вот 260 строка, на которую указывает ошибка

```
Element mc_element = doc.select(code).get(numImport);
```

Comment: В чём, собственно, ваш вопрос?

Comment: В чем, собственно, причина ошибки)

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` вот и причина. Видимо данных нет, но вы всё равно пытаетесь их прочитать.

Comment: Как правильно прописать эксепшены, чтобы при отсутствии данных не вылетало приложение, а просто выдавало какой-то тост? (извиняюсь если ответ очевидный)

Comment: Лучше проверить наличие данных перед попыткой их достать, чем полагаться на эксепшн. Потому что исключение может возникнуть и по какой-то другой причине, а вы об этом и не узнаете. Если всё-таки хотите через эксепшн, то можете заменить `IOException` на `Exception`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` в данном примере говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь получить данные, которых нет. Перед получение следует проверить, есть ли вообще эти данные:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
if (!doc.select(code).isEmpty()) {
    Element mc_element = doc.select(code).get(numImport);
    stackInfo = mc_element.text();
}
```

> приложение падает (хотя экспешены вроде все прописаны)

Вы ловите только `IOException`, а на деле получаете `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, который остаётся непойманым. Чтобы ловить все исключения, нужно указывать тип `Exception`.

Но данный способ обработки ошибок я не рекомендую, так как могут возникнуть какие-то другие исключения, о которых вы даже не узнаете.